# How to use caching to improve performance of OAuth2 ResourceServer in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am trying to use externalized Authorization Server and Resource Server protected with OAuth2. Spring Boot allows multiple ways of securing Resource Server with externalized Authorization Server by using RemoteTokenServices or providing user-info-uri. I am using user-info-uri for validating tokens on the resource server.

With this arrangement whenever a request reaches a ResourceServer it simply makes a REST call to user-info-uri using OAuth2RestTemplate. This will overwhelm Authorization Server when there is increased traffic. That is why I want to cache the results for the first call and in the subsequent calls I will check the presence of Token in the cache. If it is present I want to simply allow the request to reach the controller else I want to call user-info-uri.

How to achieve this. I am using JWT for tokens. I know when I use JWT I could provide public key to the resource server but I am not sure if it is the good way since I have too many Resource Servers.

I tried providing UserInfoRestTemplateCustomizer Bean as suggested in here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2-boot-resource-server-custom-user-info but not sure what to do here.

Comment: *I know when I use JWT I could provide public key to the resource server but I am not sure if it is the good way since I have too many Resource Servers.* Why do you think the number of resource server are important? It is just one public key of your authorization server.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will want to supply a custom implementation of the User Service which is used by the Spring Security Context, when it converts a JWT to the AuthenticationContext.  The default behavior will call out to the User Info Endpoint, should you have one configured.

It is possible to provide a custom OidcUserService when configuring the security context.  From https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2login-advanced-oidc-user-service

[image]

Another alternative is apply a custom JwtAuthenticationConverter (see HttpSecurity.oauth2ResourceServer().jwtAuthenticationConverter ), which can deal with issues when converting a jwt to authentication.  Check out https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2resourceserver-authorization

Hope this helps

Comment: after some research I found that OAuth2UserService part of spring-security-oauth2-client, does that means should my application have to be OAuthClient or it can still be ResourceServer and import the client dependency. Can you give me a clarity. Also this support seems to be added in Spring Security 5.1, but in my current project we are using 5.0. What are the available choices in 5.0?

Comment: If memory serves, support for OAuth2 in Spring Security was originally in its own project. (https://spring.io/projects/spring-security-oauth).  I can't recall when Spring Security started adding OAuth2 support directly itself.  If you're using the older Spring Security without its in-built OAuth2 functionality, check the documentation for the separate project.  Personally, I would look to upgrade as the OAuth2 support in 5.1 is pretty good.  But, if you are unable to, check the other doco.  I can't recall if they have the same setup for oidcUserService

Answer (score 1):

I found that the default handling did not give me the control I wanted. These were my requirements:
https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/

Here is the [code I ended up using](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.javaspringboot/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sample/plumbing/oauth/OAuthAuthorizer.java), since I could not get the claims I wanted into the access token.

My example is a little complex but I hope it helps you understand some options for extending Spring Boot default processing ..